# WordPress ACLs and PCPs

Tags: wordpress, pcp, acl, personal-campaign-pages

This is I'm sure specific to WordPress as I get the impression from reading that ACLs in Wordpress are as well developed as in Drupal or Joomla.

Currently, to give someone access to the "Personal Campaign Pages" option under the Contributions menu you have to turn on the "Administer CiviCRM" access level. Which is kind of a problem as it turns on a whole bunch of other features as well.

Any advice on how I can set up an ACL for just managing PCPs?